# Custom Tab Order macro and functional disabilities when second Excel Workbook opened

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of document templates created in Excel macro-enabled workbooks with an array of different macros coded in vba. I'm fairly new to vba, but I was able to cobble together code from several different sources that mostly achieved what I was looking to do: create a customized tab order, which also incorporates ActiveX Comboboxes.

For the most part, all code in each modules works great on the respective files saved locally on my machine. However, if these files are Emailed or saved on an intranet site or somewhere where they must be downloaded by end-users, something squirrelly happens that I haven't been able to sort out. When the first file is opened, the user will receive Excel's "Protected View" prompt, requiring that they click the "Enable Editing" box to access/modify the file. This is fine and the user can manipulate the first xlsm file without issue. However, with that first xlsm file open, if they additionally open any of the other xlsm workbooks that I've created (with ostensibly identical code), they are *not* prompted with the "Protected View" message and the following happens in that second workbook:

1. The cell focus is redirected to cell A1 instead of whichever cell should have been selected when the second workbook was opened,
2. The customized tab order I've delineated is disabled,
3. Both the horizontal and vertical scrollbars vanish from view, and
4. All tabs for each sheet in the second workbook are no longer visible.

I've tried manipulating and rewriting the code in each of these workbooks every which way I could think of, but I can't figure out what could be the culprit causing the above issues. I'd wager it has something to do with how Excel is initializing the second workbook when it's been downloaded, and that it has more to do with the code in the ThisWorkbook module -- here are the snippets that I think are relevant:

```
Private Sub DisableTabbing()

If Not (Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing) 
Then Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
End If

Application.OnKey "{TAB}"
Application.OnKey "+{TAB}"
Application.OnKey "~"
Application.OnKey "+~"
Application.OnKey "{ENTER}"
Application.OnKey "+{ENTER}"
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
EnableTabbing
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
DisableTabbing
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
EnableTabbing
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
DisableTabbing
End Sub
```

On my machine, I don't encounter this at all when any two workbooks are locally saved and opened, but *only* when the files are Emailed/downloaded. I'm sure there's a relatively simple fix for this, but I'm not as experienced with VBA, so I'm hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction. Is there something in the code that could be causing that, or better yet, some additional code that I could insert that would prevent it from happening?

Comment: After downloading the file, do you go to its properties and "unblock" it? By default downloaded files that can contain harmful code have those features disabled. https://thirtysix.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202921675-How-to-Unblock-a-File-Downloaded-from-an-Email-or-the-Internet

Comment: Thanks braX! That works perfectly if the workbooks are intentionally saved locally, and then manually unblocked prior to opening, but if they are opened directly from an Email for instance (which is how these will get distributed), users won't be able to unblock it prior to opening the file. Is there any way to force this unblock mechanism through VBA? That's kind of in line with what I was trying to accomplish with the bit of code related to the ActiveProtectedViewWindow.

Comment: No, it's a security feature you cannot disable on the user's machine.